# Is the blockchain size on disk smaller with v0.10.0?

Tags: blockchain-size

The [release notes](https://getmonero.org/2016/09/19/monero-0.10.0-released.html) for version v0.10.0 announce "major space saving gains for the blockchain, despite the performance improvements".

How big are these saving gains ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

User /u/blasium [reports](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/53hwaw/new_monero_version_0100_wolfram_warptangent/d7tce04) on Reddit that:

> FYI: The blockchain went from 17 GB to 8 GB for me

The exact decrease may vary depending on your setup (such as OS and filesystem).

Comment: I comfirm a space saving similar from 18.3GB to 8.3GB. Very impressed.

Answer (score 6):

Mine went from 13gb to 7.6gb for me so yes, the 0.10.0 version is definitely more compact. I run the 64 bit linux version and built the binaries on my machine. The old version was running 0.9.4